# Voiceless noun endings with voiced verb endings

Tags: etymology, parts-of-speech, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, derivational-morphology

- We can **use** that idea.
- That idea has no conceivable **use**.
- It is necessary to **house** these students.
- The will reside in that **house**.
- I cannot **prove** that.
- I have no **proof**.
- I can **breathe**.
- Every **breath** I take is worth it.
- **Live** long and prosper.
- Have a long **life**.
- **Save** your money.
- Your money is **safe**.

Here we have pairs in which a verb ends with a voiced consonant and a corresponding noun with a corresponding voiceless consonant (except that "safe" is a noun perhaps only in the sense in which that term is used in a Latin grammar that I saw that was published in 1709, and disinguished between two kinds of "nouns": substantives and adjectives).

- Is there a name for this sort of pair?
- Is there any list of such pairs in standard use in English?

Comment: Related: [Why are “using” and “user” pronounced with “s” as “z” while “use” just uses “s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275218), [When does “e” at the end of a noun change it to a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138089)

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Comment: @Kris : Can you be more specific? This is a question about one language, not about language in general.

Comment: Linguistics is also about the characteristics and idiosyncrasies of  individual languages.

Comment: I see someone has down-voted this question when no one has verbally expressed any objection to it. If I call this cowardice then someone will be offended, so I won't do that.

Comment: Interesting question! +1. I have also noticed this phenomenon and I searched a lot but I did not find any useful information. If I found anything useful, I'll answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a name for this, but it is a well-established phenomenon of English.

Other examples are

- belief/believe
- grief/grieve
- bath/bathe
- mouth/mouth
- wreath/wreathe
- glass/glaze
- grass/graze
- brass/braze

Comment: I don't know why I missed "belief/believe" in my list.

Comment: loose/lose.  close/close.

Comment: Both rather special cases, @MichaelHardy: _Loose_ and _close_ are primarily adjectives, It's not clear that _loose_ is cognate with _lose_ (though it has influenced its pronunciation), and _close_ (n) with an /s/ is a special meaning. _close_ (n) with /z/ is closer (!) in meaning to close (v).

Comment: half/halve.  ..........

Comment: Good. And _calf/calve_.

Comment: breath/breathe. cloth/clothe.

Comment: _Breath/breathe_ was in your original post.

Comment: I see. One of the problems in making a list is that you have to keep a list.